# php Monitoring live log for changes

Tags: php, file, logging

I'm trying to watch a plain text file for any changes. I want to use PHP and read the file line by line as new lines are added.

Some times 1 line may be added, other times dozens of lines could be added.  I want to read each line and check if it matches any key words..

This is what I've got so far, but it's not line by line... if buffer based.

```
<?php
$file='log.txt';
$line = $lastpos = 0;
while (true) {
    usleep(500000);
    clearstatcache(false, $file);
    $len = filesize($file);
    if ($len < $lastpos) {
        $lastpos = $len;
    }
    elseif ($len > $lastpos) {
        $f = fopen($file, "rb");
        if ($f === false) die();
        fseek($f, $lastpos);
        while (!feof($f)) {
            $buffer = fread($f, 4096);
                if ($lastpos > 0) {
                    if (strpos($buffer, 'MATCH') !== false) echo "$line\r\n";
                }
            flush();
            $line++;
        }
        $lastpos = ftell($f);
        fclose($f);
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction. Ideally I don't want to keep the log in memory as it could grow to a reasonable size.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-init.php).

Comment: Dispatch the log entry to an event listener for evaluation; if you can't, file logging is probably the wrong strategy, as e.g. DB logging could be.

Comment: Changing `$buffer = fread($f, 4096);` to `$buffer = fgets($f, 4096);` seems to have helped.